# query() Dosent Work Inside a Function

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm making a script using PHP and PDO syntax.
And before I start I wanted to make some shortcuts for me.
`$db->query() = qr()` and `$string->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) = fet($string)`

but a problem pops up on my page, that `query()` doesn't work inside a function

> ( **Fatal error**: Call to a member function query() on a non-object )

Here's my code

```
// $db->query() = qr()
function qr($str)
{
    return $db->query($str);
}
// $string->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) = fet($string)
function fet($dbq)
{
    return $dbq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

$qr = qr("select * from example");
$fet = fet($qr);

echo "".$fet->example."";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/285587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$db` is not available in function. You have to pass it via function parameter.

```
function qr($db, $str)
{
    return $db->query($str);
}
```

[Don't use Global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Comment: Any reason to downvote?

Comment: These 2 users seem suspicious. Hmm

Comment: @JmVerastigue Which 2 users?

Comment: Us eR and user. Both created 2 days ago and have the same picture. Almost same username too.

Comment: @JmVerastigue It may be coincidence.